# DotNetZip Creates Subfolders Containing the File Paths

Tags: c#, dotnetzip

I `.zip` a file using `DotNetZip`, but inside contains subfolders of the actual filepath.

Example:  Open Zip > (Users) folder > (Admin) folder > (Desktop) folder > file1.csv

May I know where I should change to that the .zip only contains the file itself?

```
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
{
    zip.Password = "password";
    zip.AddFile("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\File1.csv");
    zip.Save("Encrypted_File1.zip");
}
```

I am unsure how to change the `.AddFile` statement as there is no declaration of file path anywhere else.

Comment: Please read [ask] and show your research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://documentation.help/DotNetZip/202e1fb5-8891-888f-8e91-1340f7cd80c9.htm), I believe you need to write it like this:

```
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
{
    zip.Password = "password";
    zip.AddFile("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\File1.csv", "Admin\\Desktop\\File1.csv");
    zip.Save("Encrypted_File1.zip");
}
```

P.S. If you're doing many files and you have a common base path, you could use something like `Path.GetRelativePath` to get the in-zip path:

```
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
{
    string commonBasePath = "C:\\Users";

    // for each file
    string filePath = "C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\File1.csv";
    string inZipPath = Path.GetRelativePath(commonBasePath, filePath);
    zip.Password = "password";
    zip.AddFile(filePath, inZipPath);
    // done

    // save
    zip.Save("Encrypted_File1.zip");
}
```

Comment: Hi @John, thank you for your advice. I tried your method of `zip.AddFile`, but the `.zip` file did not appear in the directory. I am doing trial and error on some inputs to see what might work.

Comment: If the zip file didn't appear in the directory, I would suspect you're looking in the wrong directory. Anyway, that's outside the scope of this question since you would have had the same problem with your original code.